# Html code to select from list to other list not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not working much with html but I need to have two lists where I can select from one list to another. like :

[image]

this is the html code but the selection from one list to the other is not working :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
$().ready(function() {  
   $('#add').click(function() {  
    return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');  
   });  
   $('#remove').click(function() {  
    return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');  
   });  
  });
</script>
<style type="text/css" media=screen>
a {  
   display: block;  
   border: 1px solid #aaa;  
   text-decoration: none;  
   background-color: #fafafa;  
   color: #123456;  
   margin: 2px;  
   clear:both;  
  }  
  div {  
   float:left;  
   text-align: center;  
   margin: 10px;  
  }  
  select {  
   width: 100px;  
   height: 80px;  
  } 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>  
  <select multiple id="select1">  
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>  
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>  
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>  
   <option value="4">Option 4</option>  
  </select>  
  <a href="#" id="add">add &gt;&gt;</a>  
 </div>  
 <div>  
  <select multiple id="select2"></select>  
  <a href="#" id="remove">&lt;&lt; remove</a>  
 </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

I'm just not seeing what my mistake is.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: I'd say the first step is to debug the jQuery code step by step. Does `$('#select2 option:selected')` actually find an object?

Comment: Console messages? and what happens if you remove `).ready(` from the start and add the jQuery library to your code too

Comment: just use document.ready as mentioned by @PSR . see fidde here http://jsfiddle.net/FWXTn/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use document.ready .you placed wrong code

replace

```
$().ready(function()
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

try to put

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

you did not included jQuery files.

use the following code to remove and append options.

```
$('#select1:selected').each(function(i, selected) {
    $("#select2").append('<option 
     value='+$(selected).val()+'>'+$(selected).text()+'</option>');

    $(this).remove();  
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan: yeah I think it does work.  `$.fn.ready` doesn't take the `this` object into account, it only returns it.

Comment: of course : I didn't include the jQuery files.  Stupid me!  Thx a lot, just didn't see it.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a working example here http://www.bootply.com/126254

```js
$('.add').click(function(){
    $('.all').prop("checked",false);
    var items = $("#list1 input:checked:not('.all')");
    var n = items.length;
   if (n > 0) {
      items.each(function(idx,item){
        var choice = $(item);
        choice.prop("checked",false);
        choice.parent().appendTo("#list2");
      });
   }
    else {
    alert("Choose an item from list 1");
    }
});

$('.remove').click(function(){
    $('.all').prop("checked",false);
    var items = $("#list2 input:checked:not('.all')");
 items.each(function(idx,item){
      var choice = $(item);
      choice.prop("checked",false);
      choice.parent().appendTo("#list1");
    });
});

/* toggle all checkboxes in group */
$('.all').click(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 var $this = $(this);
    if($this.is(":checked")) {
     $this.parents('.list-group').find("[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",true);
    }
    else {
     $this.parents('.list-group').find("[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",false);
        $this.prop("checked",false);
    }
});

$('[type=checkbox]').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

/* toggle checkbox when list group item is clicked */
$('.list-group a').click(function(e){
  
    e.stopPropagation();
  
   var $this = $(this).find("[type=checkbox]");
    if($this.is(":checked")) {
     $this.prop("checked",false);
    }
    else {
     $this.prop("checked",true);
    }
  
    if ($this.hasClass("all")) {
     $this.trigger('click');
    }
});
```

```css
.v-center {
  min-height:200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h3>Pick List Example</h3></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
          <div class="list-group" id="list1">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">List 1 <input title="toggle all" type="checkbox" class="all pull-right"></a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">More item <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Another <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 v-center">
       <button title="Send to list 2" class="btn btn-default center-block add"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
            <button title="Send to list 1" class="btn btn-default center-block remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
       <div class="list-group" id="list2">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">List 2 <input title="toggle all" type="checkbox" class="all pull-right"></a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Alpha <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Charlie <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Bravo <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```